# cannot load such file -- 1.9/bcrypt_ext (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, bcrypt

Hey I get the following Error when i try to start the rails server

Any ideas? At the moment no possible solution worked...

By the way I run Windows 8... might be the problem at all :D

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- 1.9/bcry
pt_ext (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Enno/RubymineProjects/BookWriting2.0/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm running on windows 7 also experiencing the same issue with "cannot load such file — 1.9/bcrypt_ext (LoadError)"

Comment: you might want to restart your local server after the changes mentioned above - that might save you some time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This morning, I'm facing the same issue too (Windows 7).
Let me recommend to have a look here 
https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/72

I successfully fix my problem like this (updating my Gemfile):

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

Comment: FYI, the official bcrypt-ruby 3.1.1 have been released (including this fix)

Comment: The relevant version will constantly change. 
You can find the newest stable version number here: https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby

Answer (score 4):

If you have problems with the gem `bcrypt`, follow these steps:

**1.** Change to the gem directory found by `bundle show bcrypt` + `ext\mri\`, for example: `c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.10-x86-mingw32\ext\mri`

**2.** run `ruby extconf.rb`

**3.** run `make`

**4.** `make install`

Note that this works only if your `DevKit` environment is correctly setup (run `devkitvars.bat`).

Comment: That was it. My DevKit path was not set, so `bcrypt` was not built. I had to add `C:\DevKit2\bin;C:\DevKit2\mingw\bin` to my path. These other answers are silly. Devise doesn't even depend on `bcrypt-ruby`. https://rubygems.org/gems/devise All they are doing is adding another gem which depends on `bcrypt`, and maybe it gets built this time, maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue but with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 3.2.15 on Windows. It now requires at least 3.1.2:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
```

Link:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12325

Answer (score -1):

Comment off "gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'" in your gemfile
this should be work

Answer (score -1):

The relevant version will constantly change. You can find the newest stable version number here: rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is still having issues with this (especially with devise) on Windows 64 bit, try installing Ruby 64 bit, then rails as a gem (rather than using the rails installer) and then add:
`gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0', :require => "bcrypt"`

You may need to change your `tzinfo-data` gem to:
`gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]`

Comment: `bcrypt-ruby` already depends on `bcrypt`, so you don't need `:require`, and `devise` doesn't depend on `bcrypt-ruby` so you don't even need it at all. `devise` depends on `bcrypt` only. See https://rubygems.org/gems/devise and https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby