# Rails: "This error occurred while loading the following files: bcrypt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt, railstutorial.org

Comment on the downvoting: This question has erroneously been marked as duplicate. It is clear from the gemfile which I have attached that I am using a more recent version of bcrypt. This and other differences (I am using Ubuntu 12.04 whereas the other thread mentions Windows) makes the solution of that other thread inapplicable to my case. I am still having the issue and would welcome any advice.

=end of comment

I'm working through the famous Rails tutorial but got stuck at [Listing 7.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-user_show_action) - I think I followed all instructions but instead of getting [image: UserPage1] I'm getting [image: bcryptError]. The actual error stack is:

```
app/models/user.rb:6:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `show'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
bcrypt
Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"1"}
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

Here is the User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Here is the routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users # replaces: get "users/new"
root  'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'

end
```

And here is the user_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
def new
end
end
```

Can you tell where is the problem?

Comment: Lets discuss and debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- 1.9/bcrypt\_ext (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536635/cannot-load-such-file-1-9-bcrypt-ext-loaderror)

Comment: @phoet No, it does not seem to be a duplicate. The bcrypt version that I am using is a more recent one. Also, I am on Ubuntu 12.04 whereas that SO thread is about Windows. The advice there does not seem applicable to my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Curiuosly, restarting the WEBrick server eliminated the problem. This was done after a system re-boot preceded by a partial upgrade of the system (Ubuntu 12.04) as response to an unrelated issue ([the Heartbleed bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-the-heartbleed-bug-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl)) so I don't really know whether it was just the WEBrick restart which eliminated the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It was the WEBrick restart which fixed your problem. The rails console output would have been displaying the error:

```
You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt):
```

This was caused because after installing the bcrypt gem for "A Hashed Password" (section 6.3.1   in the tutorial) there is no explicit instruction to restart the server.