# Rails cannot load such file -- bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app loads locally but any interaction throws an error:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-22 15:42:14 +1100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (37.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1007ms (Views: 978.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)


Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-22 15:42:29 +1100   
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt):

app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `new'
  Rendering C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action
```

I am running Windows7 64bit, Ruby23-x64, Rails 5.0.0.1 and the only bcrypt gem I have installed is: bcrypt-3.1.11.

I attempted the solution here: [cannot load such file -- 1.9/bcrypt_ext (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536635/cannot-load-such-file-1-9-bcrypt-ext-loaderror) but bcrypt-ruby no longer exists with newer versions of ruby.

Edit: If I run gem install bcrypt, I get an additional bcrypt gem in: C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems. I now have 2 bcrypts:

- C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.11
- C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32

Which one do I keep, and what do I need to change in my Gemfile?

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the `bcrypt` gem correctly installed?

Comment: try adding the gem file like, `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'`

Comment: try the next version of `bcrypt`, `3.1.2`

Comment: @Sravan 3.1.2 is actually older, I am using 3.1.11 which I can see is the newest: https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt/versions/ as of today.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida within my directory: C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems I have: bcrypt-3.1.11 so I believe so. How else can I test that it's installed correctly?

Comment: First of all, when you run `bundle install` it says it installed `bcrypt` gem correctly? Th native extensions were built correctly? You may know by just reading all messages of the `bundle install` command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You put this `gem 'bcrypt'` into your `Gemfile`.

If you put it and ran `bundle install`, did you `restart` your `rails server` ?

If you still had this problem, you can do this as follow:

- Firstly uninstall `bcrypt` and `bcrypt-ruby` by running these two commands:

  `gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`
- Install it again with `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`
- In your `Gemfile` write `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'`
- Then run `bundle install` and `restart` your `rail server`

Comment: I put 'gem bcrypt' in my Gemfile and ran 'bundle install' before my rails server was started. I then restarted the rails server anyway, and the issue persists.

Comment: @rlsaj i've just updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: thanks that fixed it - oddly I had to go back all the way to 3.1.5 for this to work. Now I have other errors, but this specific error is now resolved.